# ER_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK_DURING_COMMIT MySQL error when querying

Tags: mysql-5.7, group-replication

I've recently seen a high number of errors on my Bugsnag integration of my web app which occur when both reading or writing to my MySQL server.

`ER_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK_DURING_COMMIT: Plugin instructed the server to rollback the current transaction`
[image]

For a bit of background on how my MySQL servers are setup:

I currently have a "cluster" of MySQL servers running on 5 VMs which are running the Group Replication plugin in multi-master mode with the following config:
[image]

[image]

I've searched for the MySQL error code `ER_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK_DURING_COMMIT` online as well as on stackoverflow, and as far as I can see, I can not find anything that helps me find the cause of this issue or the resolution.

Unfortunately I don't have any more information other than this, but if you require anything specific to help me, please do ask.

Thanks, Dan.

Edit: Added Group Replication config

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: @mustaccio My question is what is the possible cause of this and resolution? Because I've looked around on Google and StackOverflow and I've not found anyone with a similar issue.